# Cygwin key-based auth

Tags: cygwin, cygwin-sshd

I have a server running Windows 2003 that is using Cygwin's SSHD.  Where do I save my public key to in order to allow key-based auth?  The Linux equivalent is ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.

Answer (score 3):

I you have installed Cygwin with its own installer, you should already have a /home/ directory, which acts the very same as a *NIX home directory. If you installed SSH server without the Cygwin installer, your home directory should be your Windows home, which usually is C:\Users\. The .ssh/ directory should be right under the home directory, just like for Unices.